# IE9 Float32Array error, while Firefox and Chrome are OK

Tags: internet-explorer-9, playn

I created a game with playn version 1.1, using SurfaceLayer to draw Images into it.

with the java backend no problem,
with the html backend:
Firefox OK,  Chrome OK,
while using IE9 returns **failed to init (reference error)  Float32Array**

I'm using windows 7 64

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The IE bug is fixed in PlayN version 1.1.1.

Comment: perfect, now it's working, but I noticed a strange behaviour: sprites are going in the "wrong sense".. similar to
http://xna-platformer.appspot.com/Platformer.html  , if you try to go left/right,
it only happens using  IE9